# Запуск одноименной программы из кода

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем привет есть необходимость запустить файл из приложения одноименный с запущенным приложением - "test.exe",
 проблема в том что таких файла два и они находятся в разных директориях,
 а в Process.Start(File Name); путь не укажешь и что он откроет неизвестно 
Собственно вопрос как открыть файл по адресу?

Comment: «в Process.Start(File Name); путь не укажешь» — эээ, а почему вдруг? А вы попробуйте всё же указать.

Comment: @VladD Process.Start() принимает 5 перегрузок я их все рассмотрел

Comment: Хм. А чем вам не подходит эта: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s(v=vs.110).aspx?

Comment: @VladD спасибо я просто в Intelisence смотрел перегрузки, поэтому не увидел)